# Skip the contents of an element in SAX parsing in Java

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I am parsing a custom XML configuration file in a Java application. I am trying to use the SAX parser, mainly because I need to report errors in the configuration with line numbers.

There are a lot of code samples online of implementing a handler class, and things seem fairly straightforward for normal processing - for example, http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-example.html

But in my case, sometimes I need to skip an entire tree under an element:

```
<sampledocument>
    <sampletag>
         <process/>
         <these/>
         <tags/>
    </sampletag>
    <sampletag skip="yes">
         <do_not>
         <process/>
         <these/>
         <tags/>
    </sampletag>
<sampledocument>
```

LATER ADDITION: Moreover, I only know whether to skip at runtime. In a somewhat contrived example, I would need to open a file to process the tags under `<sampletag>`, and if the file is not found, not process them:

```
<sampledocument>
    <sampletag file="file1">
         <process/>
         <these/>
         <tags/>
         <if_file1_exists/>
    </sampletag>
    <sampletag file="file2">
         <process/>
         <these/>
         <tags/>
         <if_file2_exists/>
    </sampletag>
<sampledocument>
```

Of course, I can just track skipping in the handler code, but this is a bit awkward. Can I somehow tell SAX in the startElement() method to just skip the contents of this element?

Answer (score 2):

Write a filter class to sit on the pipeline between the SAX parser and your existing ContentHandler. You can do this by extending `XMLFilterImpl`. This filter should have an integer variable skipDepth, initially zero.

In startElement, if you recognize an element that you want to deep-skip, or if skipDepth > 0, then increment skipDepth.

In endElement, if skipDepth > 0, decrement skipDepth.

In all event handlers, pass the event on down the pipeline (by calling super.xxx()) if and only if skipDepth == 0.

If you want to be smart, you can write this filter in a generic way, so it takes a parameter which is a callback function that accepts the node name and attributes and returns a boolean indicating whether to skip the element. Then you can reuse your code next time you want to skip elements, but with different skip conditions.

Comment: Thanks! But how is this different from simply maintaining skipDepth in the ContentHandler? In my real task, the ContentHandler must actually process the element before determining whether to skip a tree, so if I have a separate filter, the ContentHandler wil have to trigger the skipping anyway.

Comment: SAX code is always best written as a pipeline, one step in the pipeline for each separable task. Otherwise you quickly end up with spaghetti code in your ContentHandler (you already said it was "a bit awkward"). With a properly constructed pipeline you end up with maintainable, reusable code that is easy to modify and debug; if you put everything in the ContentHandler you end up with an unmaintainable mess. Of course, if your example differs from the real task then I can't advise you how to break up the functionality in the real task.

Comment: I have modified the example to test for files at runtime. The real code verifies correctness of the configuration, explaining how it verifies it would make a very long question, but it is a call to a separate class - so somewhat similar to checking for a file.

Comment: Changing the question in such a way as to invalidate existing answers is just thoroughly unfriendly.

Comment: Sorry - I did get thoroughly confused. I have restored the previous example and placed the new one after it, seeing as providing the new one in a comment is impossible.